# jQuery Datepicker in Directive can't handle same IDs in different forms

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

On my html page I dynamically include/remove instances of one form using **ng-include**. So each ng-model inside of it should be created in its separate scope. The only thing I do is change ID of form by increment index, but the input fields conserve same IDs.

html page may look like this:

```
<form id="form_1">
     <label for="birthdate">Applicant DOB</label>
     <input id="birthdate" ng-model="birthdate" datepicker>
     ...    
</form>

<form id="form_2">
     <label for="birthdate">Applicant DOB</label>
     <input id="birthdate" ng-model="birthdate" datepicker> 
     ...    
</form>

<form id="form_3">
     <label for="birthdate">Applicant DOB</label>
     <input id="birthdate" ng-model="birthdate" datepicker> 
     ...    
</form>
```

So I have problems using jQuery Datepicker directive:

```
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function(){
                element.datepicker({
                    onSelect:function (date) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

When i set date on **form_1** it is fine, but when I set date on **form_2** or **form_3** it does not set anything there, but changes value of form_1 always.

I know it is wrong to have same IDs inside 1 form, but is right to have same IDs in different forms. Seems like this library can't handle this case. ((

Answer (score 0):

IDs are globally unique for the page, as defined by [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). You can't expect any javascript library to behave properly if you are targeting non-unique IDs as it's not something libraries test and there's no reason to give guarantees on behavior.

In this instance, you should likely be targeting elements using classes.

Comment: any suggestion on targeting elements using classes?

Comment: @RenatGatin no, sorry. I'm much more familiar with react+reflux than Angular. I just happen to notice the form ids.